# Using MonetDB grouping sets with Pentaho Mondrian

Tags: sql, pentaho, mondrian, monetdb, grouping-sets

I know MonetDB supports grouping sets. I also know that Mondrian supports them too, but only in a couple of databases.

Is it possible to enable SQL groupings sets in Mondrian for MonetDB database?

Thank you!

Comment: I guess it's always _possible_ to enable it. The question is more about who has the time to implement it.  Maybe you can add an enhancement request here: https://github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB/issues ?

Comment: @Jennie Thank you! I've already added the request. I'm very interested in this feature.

Comment: got it, thanks for the ticket.  the open-source team will work on it when they can, so, no guarantee for the timeline

Comment: @Jennie Don't worry about time: I know you have to evaluate this feature's value for the product. Thank you again and I really appreciate your effort.